# how to save a pdf with action script from a browser?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a problem with my script, I create a pdf file with data and script inside and I show this pdf in a browser.
The user can put more data y has a button that calls a script action for to save, in this part my script does not work.

This is the code in the web page:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        function doSubmit() {
            pdfObject = document.getElementById("PDFObj");
            try{ pdfObject.postMessage(["submitForm", "submitForm"]);  }
            catch (e)
            { alert( "Error: \n name = " + e.name + "\n message = " + e.message ); }
       }
</script> 
<p align="center">
<object id="PDFObj" align="center" data="../pdf/form.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="500" height="200"></object>
</p>
```

This is my script:

```
<action type="javascript"><![CDATA[
            var mydoc = app.activeDocument;

            function myOnMessage(aMessage){

                if (aMessage[0] == 'submitForm'){

                    try {     
                    var myPath = "/d/temp/" + "file" + ".pdf";
                    this.saveAs(myPath);
                    app.alert("the records was successful" );
                    }catch (e)
                    { app.alert("Error:" + e.Message);} 

                }
            }

            var msgHandlerObject = new Object();
            msgHandlerObject.onMessage = myOnMessage;
            msgHandlerObject.onError = myOnError;
            msgHandlerObject.onDisclose = myOnDisclose;
            function myOnDisclose(cURL,cDocumentURL){
            return true;    }
            function myOnError(error, aMessage){
            app.alert(error);
            }
            this.hostContainer.messageHandler = msgHandlerObject;
            ]]>
         </action>
```

Please, I need to know why does not work my script and a possible solution.

Comment: I do not see how this question is related to Action Script.Action Script is the programming language for Flash/Flex/Air applications,it is somehow similar to Javascript (not so much after version 2.0), and it this has nothing to do with Javascript for PDF actions.

Comment: @yms I think the OP is not aware that ActionScript is a language, and used it to mean an action that could be done/controled via script

Comment: I use Adobe Air for call a function from web, into this function I have to save the PDF.

Comment: You have to explain the situation a bit better. Right now I do not understand if the code you posted is action script, or javascript, or if it is inside the PDF, or in a web page.

Comment: For starting, I am 99% sure you cannot this in a web environment, but you also mentioned Adobe Air, which is not a web environment. So please provide more context so that we can help.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here but, i think he is showing the pdf in a new window from an Air application, but if that's the case, why would you need a save buttom... we need more context here.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response, I will update the information with all code.